# Bootstrap Inline form - Horizontal stacked inputs and button

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a design, where there are 4 input fields ending with a Search Button i.e.

```
                        INPUT1 INPUT2 INPUT3 INPUT4 BUTTON
```

I need all these to be stacked horizontally inside a form tag and should be inline with out any padding or spaces, showing at the center of the page on top of a banner. Need to accomplish this using bootstrap.

Regards,
Sijo Jose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
<form>
  <div class="input-container">
     <div class="inline-content">
         <input type="text" value="input 1">
         <input type="text" value="input 2">
         <input type="text" value="input 3">
         <input type="text" value="input 4">
         <button type="button">button</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

I have also created a Bootply. Here is the link. http://www.bootply.com/XlBQ3QRLGN

Comment: You're welcome. you can mark it as answered. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Below code might help

HTML Code :-

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="inner">
      <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:-

```
div {
  min-height:75px;
  line-height:75px;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;

}

.inner {
  width:100%;
  max-width:960px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.header {
  background:red;
}
```

Using form-inline using bootstrap :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
form {

    margin: 0 auto;
}


  </style>
</head>
<body>

<form class="form-inline">
  <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="inputone">

  <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="inputtwo">

   <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="inputthree">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Shabarish! Is there any way to do this in bootstrap using the form-line classes..

Comment: yes you can even do it using form-line classes . I have updated my answer it might help you

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <label class="text-inline">
      <input type="text">
    </label>
    <label class="text-inline">
      <input type="text">
    </label>
     <label class="text-inline">
      <input type="text">
    </label>
     <label class="btn-inline">
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </label>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```